# How to remove the @ / extended metadata of a file?

Tags: macos, file-permissions, ls

I know that the @ in

```
-rwxrwxrwx@ 1 me  staff     0 16 Mai 10:55 myLog.txt
```

means, that there is some extended metadata attached.

Fine. Doesn't interest me.

I need to know how to remove it ?

I get this again and again while in developing stage of some php scripts. And again and again my logfiles get blocked by the @ and my scripts can't write into the log-files anymore. My only solution so far: remove the file and recreate it and rechmod the permissions of the file, which of course sucks.

And maybe you can tell me what is causing it ? It seems completly random. Can I deactivate this blocking @

## Edit and Solution:

Thanks to the comments I have found out now that the following command removes the "@"

```
xattr -d com.macromates.caret filename
```

And the next command prevents Textmate from adding it again (close Textmate before running the command).

```
defaults write com.macromates.textmate OakDocumentDisableFSMetaData 1
```

Source and more infos [here](http://www.cloudspace.com/blog/2009/11/24/textmate-extended-attributes-corrupting-files/)

Comment: TextMate uses extended attributes (resource fork) for persisting  the caret position. Are you using TextMate? Check its preferences, you can disable this feature.

Comment: Wow, I use it indeed. So TextMate does this huh, strange that it's so random, is it buggy ?

Comment: Can't find the place in settings where I could deactivate such thing

Comment: "Blocked"? That sounds suspect...

Comment: @Allisone Glad that helped. Hope you don't mind that I re-posted as answer, I'd appreciate an accept if that's what you were actually looking for.

Comment: @Allisone this isn't a bug in TextMate, it's a bug in whatever's getting blocked by it -- `@` is a normal part of the output of `ls -l` on a Mac, and logging system really should be able to cope with it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Extended attributes are most likely added by your text editor. TextMate uses them to store e.g. the caret position. Disable that feature of to get rid of the unused extended attributes altogether.

You can delete extended attributes using

```
xattr
```

and list them using

```
ls -l@
```